# Passing map as parameter to search data from table where return type is Map in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to search data from a table where `Map<String,String>` is passed as parameter in search method. It will also return a `Map<String,String>`.

I want to solve it using Spring and Hibernate.e.g:

```
Map<String, String> findByItem(Map<String, String> q){
}
```

Comment: and your question is???

Comment: Provide more information, such as the entity you want to query, spring configuration, hibernate configuration

Comment: Say, I want to select quiestionnaireCode and questionnaireName from a table named Questionnaire according to  given   quiestionnaireCode,questionnaireName.It will be a search method

Answer (score 0):

**if you can not change method signature. i think it will be below...**

```
Map<String, String> findByItem(Map<String, String> q){
         Query listQuery = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT quiestionnaireCode, questionnaireName FROM Questionnaire WHERE quiestionnaireCode =:quiestionnaireCode AND quiestionnaireName =:quiestionnaireName");
         listQuery.setParameter("quiestionnaireCode", q.get("quiestionnaireCode");
         listQuery.setParameter("quiestionnaireName", q.get("quiestionnaireName");
         List<Questionnaire> quiestionnaireList= listQuery.list();
          Gson gson = new Gson();
          String str = gson.toJson(quiestionnaireList);
          Map<String, String> output = new HashMap<String, String>();
          output.add("result",str);
          return output;
    }
```